# Code and compile locally on a Dev-Mode Chromebook

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os

My school has given me a Samsung ARM Chromebook, and I am encourage to go into developer mode and mess around with it.

I know how to access crosh and shell, and I found that vi is installed locally on the machine, but it cannot compile programs you make.

Has anyone ever gotten compilers such as gcc, or javac to work on a Chromebook locally?  I know you can SSH into a server with such features, but it would be nice to have it off line.

Comment: The tutorial [LAMP Stack on an ARM ChromeBook  |  Solvitor](http://solvitor.com/2013/01/02/lamp-stack-on-an-arm-chromebook/) explains how to run a complete linux distro in developer mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer, I have gotten gcc and javac to run locally on my ARM Chromebook.  I used the steps that I wrote, [linked by @Dennis above](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton), to get Arch Linux up and running in a chroot.

If you prefer something other than Arch Linux, try [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) which also lets you run a graphical linux environment (several, in fact) on an ARM Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to set up a [Go](http://golang.org) environment without using Crouton as follows:

1. Download Dave Cheney's [Go v1.1.1 tarball](http://dave.cheney.net/paste/go1.1.linux-arm~armv7-multiarch-1.tar.gz) for ChromeBook (ARM v7, multiarch)
2. Install it to /usr/local/bin/go on your Chromebook, i.e. in Crosh / Shell

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/go
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo tar xvzf ~/Downloads/go1.1.linux-arm~armv7-multiarch-1.tar.gz
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/go /usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/go/bin
```

3. `go run` command doesn't work due to the Chronos security mechanisms
4. So use `go build` and copy your executable to `/usr/local/bin`

Go is mature beyond it's relative newness.  It was developed by Google to run on its servers efficiently and to be easy to deploy.  The language was developed by some of the most notable computer scientists.  So ignore the trolls and give it a go.  The [GoLang site](http://golang.org) has links to resources, wiki and videos.